# Deploy .ASMX Web Service to Windows Azure

Tags: web-services, azure

I am totally new to Azure, I have stumbled across it as a I wish to farm out a Web Service for updating our database without hosting it internally and potentially involving any security risks.

Therefore I have got myself a free Azure Web Trial to see if its worth it. I have an .ASMX based Web Service (Because this is all I know to build) and I wish to deploy it to Windows Azure.

Is this at all possible?

Cheers,

James

Answer (score 0):

Yes I've done just that myself. Add an AzureCloudService project to your solution (requires the Azure sdk); create as an empty project, do not select any web or worker roles as part of the project creation.

Under the Cloud service select Roles -> Add -> Web Role project in solution...
and select your existing web service project

From the context menu on the Cloud Service project you will be able to package or publish to Azure.

Comment: Hi Alex,

I'll give this a go this morning and let you know.

Comment: Hi Alex,

Web Role Project In Solution is greyed out for me, any ideas?

Comment: I forgot the above only works with a .net WebApplication rather than a website (I obviously made too many assumptions about your environment!), that may be the reason. I would suggest creating a new empty WebApplication and adding a WebService asmx to it then following the instructions above. This will hopefully demonstrate amsx projects will run fine within Azure. Then there is the issue of how best to migrate your project to a WebApplication...

Answer (score 0):

You could do that inside Visual Studio, right click on the name of the project and then click publish, and of course after that you will be asked to log into your azure account and with a click you'll have your web service deployed and ready to be consumed.