# Azure asmx cloud service url connection timed out

Tags: web-services, azure, visual-studio-2013

I have deployed an `asmx web service` to azure cloud service by following this stackoverflow link [Host asmx webservice to azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29752532/deploy-asmx-web-service-to-windows-azure) by using azure SDK for windows inside Visual Studio 2013.

The deployment was successful and in the `azure management portal` the service shows as running

But when I try to browse the URL the browser displays `connection timed out` message.

What could be the problem ?Is it because its an asmx web service?

Comment: Please take you  remote your Cloud service VM and check the service is running internally on localhost or not. https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-how-to-configure/

Comment: Check you are connecting to one of the endpoints defined in your ServiceDefinition.csdef. i.e. confirm that if you are trying to connect over http that the endpoint for http port 80 exists.  You can run an asmx webservice in a webrole, that is not the issue.