# Can ASP.NET SOAP XML web services run on Azure?

Tags: asp.net, xml, web-services, soap

We have a large number of legacy ASP.NET SOAP XML web services in our software system. We normally host these in IIS. I would like to know if these can be hosted on Azure with no or as little change as possible? The web services are all written in C#.

Our client is looking at using "full" Azure, not just running these in a VM in Windows using IIS on Azure.

Are there any "best practices" on "porting" ASP.NET SOAP XML web services to Azure?

Comment: may this help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29752532/deploy-asmx-web-service-to-windows-azure

Answer (score 0):

Configure the XML Web service to use Windows authentication, using IIS.
IIS allows you to specify security at either the directory or file level. If you want to specify the security for an XML Web service on a per-file basis, set the permissions for the XML Web service on the .asmx file in IIS. The .asmx file is the entry point into the XML Web service. See the IIS documentation for details.

Modify the configuration file to specify Windows authentication.
Set the mode attribute of the authentication XML element in a configuration file to "Windows". For details on how to configure a configuration file, see ASP.NET Configuration.